# why do i get a connection not secure in firefox on wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, security, ssl

I have a wordpress website and on some pages firefox shows a connection not secure error next to my ssl lock . Says some content is not secure such as images.

I do not know a thing about checking this stuff. 
Any instructions would be appreciated.
https://www.employee-no-more.com . Also does it at my other two websites

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're website does not include external resources using plain http.
Example:

```
<!-- Bad -->
<img src="http://host.com/img/bg.png">
<!-- Good -->
<img src="https://host.com/img/bg.png">
```

EDIT: Quick look at network tab in chrome dev tools reveals this request:

```
Request URL:http://img.banggood.com/deals/affiliate_member_banner/7a951116de2a4c23c74733d76046a5b413.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

So in theory it's possible to see which resource is loading as http through your browser's developer console. But I found this site here to be much easier to use to figure it out:

https://www.employee-no-more.com

It's apparently this image, on your site that is causing trouble:

http://img.banggood.com/deals/affiliate_member_banner/7a951116de2a4c23c74733d76046a5b413.jpg

So now you need to figure out who's including it, and make them request the https version...

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the information. I simply added the "s" on in the links in ads that had only http and it fixed it. It was the bangood ads. Both answers were very helpful and had accurate information that solved the problem.